# How to add a firestore document inside a firebase function with firebase function gen2 in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add a document in a firestore collection, in a firebase function. But I can't find how. I found a lot of example with the previous non-modular approach, which was something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
  
//And in inside the function:
return admin.firestore().doc('users/'+user.uid).set(userObject);
```

but the "require", firebase admin, etc are the gen1 approach. And those are prevented by typescript eslint:

> Require statement not part of import statement  @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires

How can I add some document inside of a function?

```
import { setGlobalOptions } from "firebase-functions/v2";
import { onDocumentCreated } from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";


setGlobalOptions({ region: "europe-west6" });

exports.sendEmail = onDocumentCreated("invites/{email}", (event: any) => {
  const snapshot = event.data;
  if (!snapshot) {
    console.log("No data associated with the event");
    return;
  }
  const data = snapshot.data();
  const email = {
      to: data.email,
      message: {
        subject: "You have been invited to join " + data.householdName,
        html:
          "Hello " +
          data.email +
          ",<br><br>You have been invited to join " +
          data.householdName +
          " by " +
          data.inviter +
          '.<br><br>Click <a href="https://plan-eat-ced91.web.app/">here</a> to join!',
      },
    }
  //How to do the equivalent of this in firebase?
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("mail")
    .add(email );

});
```

Comment: The APIs for using the admin SDK doesn't change at all between v1 and v2 functions. What you need to realize is that the preferred syntax for using modules in JS and TS  can differ. The error messages suggests that you are using TS with an eslint rule that rejects JS `require` statements, so you should import the SDK using an `import` statement instead. Either that or relax the eslint rule that stops you from using `require`, if that's what you really want.

Comment: For more information, do a web search for the error code in the message: "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires"

Comment: @DougStevenson What would be the way to do it with import? How to know the name of the package to be imported?

Comment: The name of the package doesn't change between import and require.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add-sdk).